# Pointwise convergence of the cdf of normal random variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

For a sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots $, Let $F_n(x)$ denote the cdf of $X_n$.

Suppose our sequence is $X_n \sim N(0,n) $ then for all $x$ the point-wise limit of $F_n(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

How would one prove this?

Comment: You should ask this on 'Mathematics'

Comment: @Hermant: While this question would be fine on math.SE, it is perfectly within the scope of Cross Validated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, let $X$ be any random variable with distribution $F$ having unit variance.  Letting $(\mu_n)$ and $(\sigma_n)$ be any sequences of numbers, set

$$X_n = \sigma_n X + \mu_n.$$

Define $F_n$ to be the distribution of $X_n$.  Suppose that as $n\to\infty$, $$\sigma_n\to\infty$$ and $$\mu_n / \sigma_n\to z.$$  **If $F$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $-z$, then the pointwise limit of $F_n(x)$ must be $F(-z)$.**

Intuitively, this is because

1. The distributions of the $X_n$ are becoming more and more spread out but
2. *Relative to the spreads* $\sigma_n$, any fixed number $x$ is becoming ever closer to $-z$.

Thus the pointwise limit ought to be $F(-z)$.

**It remains to make this intuition rigorous.**  From the basic definitions and a little bit of algebra, observe that

$$F_n(x) = \Pr(X_n \le x) = \Pr(\sigma_n X + \mu_n \le x) = \Pr\left(X \le \frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right) = F\left(\frac{x-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right).$$

The assumptions about the limiting values of $\mu_n/\sigma_n$ and $\sigma_n$ were made specifically to imply  $\lim_{n\to \infty} (x-\mu_n)/\sigma_n = -z$.  Applying the assumed continuity of $F$ in a neighborhood of $-z$ finishes the demonstration.  (The details, which are straightforward, are left to the reader because this is a self-study question that asks for guidance and intuition rather than a complete answer.)

Application of this result to the standard Normal distribution $F$, $(\mu_n) = (0)$, and $\sigma_n=(n)$ answers the question as stated, because $F(-0) = 1/2$.

Comment: Presumably $F$ should also have zero mean?

Comment: @Dougal Not at all.  The mean is irrelevant.  Because $X$ has a variance, its mean is defined and finite, but that's all we can say about the mean in general. Your intuition can help here: when $\sigma_n$ is very large, $F_n(x)$ depends only on a value of $F$ near $\mu_n/\sigma_n \approx z$, whereas the mean also depends on the chances that $X$ is extremely large or extremely small.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I see that now – I was just thrown by $\mathbb{E} X_n \ne \mu_n$.